# Putting a fragment identifier inside of a query parameter

Tags: javascript, http, url, query-string, fragment-identifier

I am trying to redirect to a URL path that contains a query parameter called `next`,  which is itself a URL path that contains a fragment identifier. Here is the JavaScript code I tried:

```
window.location.href = "/gauth?next=" + window.location.pathname + "#onload=exportToDrive"
```

Just to make myself clear, the `#onload=exportToDrive` should belong to the `next` URL path (*not* the URL that the browser is redirecting to). How can I specify that information to the browser so that it will handle this situation correctly?

Comment: In general, the entire value of the `next` parameter should be URL-encoded with something like [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Comment: @robertklep Worked like a charm! Thanks so much! If you want to make your comment into an answer, I would gladly give you an upvote and the accepted answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always encode URL parameter values properly, using a function like [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
window.location.href = "/gauth?next=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname + "#onload=exportToDrive");
```

This will ensure that any fragment identifiers (but also query string parameters) won't apply to `/gauth`.